# Onscreen keyboard to use when logging in

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard, login

I purchased a small touchscreen for my raspberry pi (running Raspbian), but I also require a login to the user pi (encrypted home directory).

How do I set up an onscreen keyboard so that I can log in to the Pi?

Ideally, it would also start automatically after login and be hidden until I need to type something (so I can use it for more than logging in), but just having an entry in the start menu would be okay.

I have done some research on this, but I have not found any that don't need a shortcut or command to start, and I have found nothing on the use of a onscreen keyboard to log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install an on-screen keyboard of your choice. `florence` will do just fine:

```
sudo apt-get install florence
```

Make sure it runs fine and configure it to your preference.

Then make sure `lightdm-gtk-greeter` is installed, and edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`, adding the command to start the virtual keyboard during login:

```
keyboard=florence --focus &
```

You also need to enable the greeter in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Upon a restart, you should see the login screen with a virtual keyboard on it.

Comment: That's quite helpful. I had never quite gotten it working, so I'll have to try this out. Unfortunately, I don't have my Pi available at the moment. I'll let you know how this turns out soon hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

Look for Matchbox.  Its a set of tools for linux that supplies things like androi-like virtual keyboards

Comment: When I search the net for "matchbox", I find nothing that seems relevant. Do you have a link or some more information?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14719

Answer (score 2):

I had never work with, but `florence`, a virtual keyboard, seems quite common in the rpi community :

[florence.sourceforge.net](http://florence.sourceforge.net)

This page also list alternatives virtual keyboard programs : GOK, XVKBD and OnBoard, wich may, or not, run on Raspbian :)

Comment: This sounds promising, but is there any way to use it with the greeter (the login screen when the Pi boots)? I'd like to have home folder encryption, but I can't use that without a way to type the password.

Comment: Look at : http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/how-to.html
It's seems feasible, at least on some windows manager